# Firebase retrieves data after the function have returned

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to swift and firebase, and I need some help. I wrote a swift2 function that can retrieve data from firebase but it didn't work.

The code is below:

```
func fetchUidWithEmail (email: String) -> String {

    var uid = ""

    ref.child("userList").queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {
                uid = snap.key
            }
        }            
    })

    return uid
}
```

I tried to print snap in the for block and it appeared after the uid value had returned. So I always got an empty string return from this function. Is there any method to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from the Firebase Database is read asynchronously. This means that the order in which your code executes is likely not what you expect. The easiest way to see this is by adding some print statements:

```
func fetchUidWithEmail (email: String) -> String {
    print("Before starting query")
    ref.child("userList").queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        print("In query callback block")
    })
    print("After starting query")
}
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before starting query
>
> After starting query
>
> In query callback block

This is probably not what you expected. But it does explain why returning the uid doesn't work: by the time you return the uid, it hasn't loaded from Firebase yet.

The way to deal with this is to change the way you think about the problem. Instead of saying "first fetch the uid, then do something with the uid" try phrasing it as "whenever we get the uid, do something with it".

The easiest way to do that is to write the code that needs the uid, into the function that loads the data:

```
func fetchUidWithEmail (email: String) -> String {    
    ref.child("userList").queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                print(snap.key)
                // TODO: do anything you want with the uid here
            }
        }            
    })
}
```

While this works, it means you may have many places where you have the loading of the uid-by-email. It is more reusable if you can pass in the code that needs the uid to your function:

```
func fetchUidWithEmail (email: String, withBlock: String -> Void) -> Void {
    ref.child("userList").queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                withBlock(snap.key)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
fetchUidWithEmail("frank.vanpuffelen@gmail.com") { (uid) in
    print(uid)
}
```

This is exactly how the Firebase Database client itself works: when you add an observer, you pass in a callback/block.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea about this kind of function. You did me a big favor! Thanks for the clear answer again!